# Include cpp-netlib with CLion and Make on macOS

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, clion

I'm very new to CLion, CMake and macOS at all so I need a little bit of help while trying to include cppnetlib into my CLion project.

I started out with creating an new CLion project which gave me a new CMakeLists.txt which I edited so that it would include boost as well:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.7)
PROJECT(myapp)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

SET(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(myapp ${SOURCE_FILES})

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.63.0 REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(dxcheck ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

I've installed boost through homebrew, but I did not find a package for cppnetlib with homebrew so I downloaded cppnetlib and placed it in /usr/local/Cellar/cpp-netlib. Now, when I follow the tutorial on their page and put

```
set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} /usr/local/Cellar/cpp-netlib)
find_package (cppnetlib 0.12.0 REQUIRED)
include_directories (${CPPNETLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries (myapp ${CPPNETLIB_LIBRARIES})
```

into the CMakeLists.txt, I get the following output:

```
-- Boost version: 1.63.0
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findcppnetlib.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "cppnetlib", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "cppnetlib"
  (requested version 0.11.0) with any of the following names:

    cppnetlibConfig.cmake
    cppnetlib-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "cppnetlib" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "cppnetlib_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "cppnetlib" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

I've already done some research about finding packages but all I could achieve was that I was able to include cppnetlib by manually adding the include path to the CMakeLists.txt but then I got an error saying that the compiler could not find the  headers which are located inside the "deps" folder in cpp-netlib.

I know want to know how to include a package like cppnetlib properly into my CLion project using CMake. I am using CLion 2017.1, macOS Sierra and I think CLion is using CMake 3.7.

Comment: If you have *cppnetlib* downloaded from [this github repo](https://github.com/cpp-netlib/cpp-netlib), then lines which installs `cppnetlibConfig.cmake` file are **commented out**. You may try to uncomment them (at the end of [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/cpp-netlib/cpp-netlib/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L160)), reinstall cppnetlib, and try to configure your project again.

Comment: By saying "reinstall", do you mean building with Make? I've uncommented these lines and then tried to build with CMake but this throws a lot of errors such as "binary directory "/usr/local/Cellar/cpp-netlib-build/deps/uri/test" is already used to build a source directory". I cloned the whole GitHub repo and moved it into the cellar folder.

Comment: nervermind I fixed this. My last issue now is that I get the following error message : export given target "cppnetlib-uri" which is not built by this project.

Comment: Hmm, you may safetly remove both `export()` commands: they are needed only for export *build tree*, but you need to export *install tree*.

Comment: When I remove the `export` commands, it doesn't create a cppnetlibTargets.cmake anymore but this file is required in order to make the cppnetlibConfig.cmake work.

Comment: Edit: I've tried using the cppnetlib version provided on the official website which does not give me any CMake errors. I am also able to properly import cppnetlib into my project and I have access to all headers. However, when I try to build my project, I'm getting an error which says that the <asio> headers could not be found. Now I'm not sure whether I have to import asio as well since it is already located under "deps" in cppnetlib.

Comment: Update: Now I've tried various versions of cpp-netlib and I've come to a solution. I Will update this question and answer it after I've done some tests.